# Cannot init the @FormBean field type as List<Integer> or Integer[]

Tags: rest, jax-rs, resteasy

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;

Hi guys, The JAX-RS seems cannot init the list field in resteasy 2.x/3.x/4.x automatically,

Here is my VO used in servce

```
public class OrderVO {  
    @FormParam("id")
    private long id;    
    @FormParam("title")
    private String title;   
    @FormParam("product")
    private List<Integer> product;

    ...
    
    public String toString() {
        return JSON.toJSONString(this);
    }
}
```

And here is my service method:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED+";charset=UTF-8")
@Path("/create")
public InsertResult saveOrder(@BeanParam OrderVO order) {
    logger.debug(order.toString());
    
}
```

Other parameters are auto inited except the List or Integer[], and can anyone tell me why....

Comment: What is the request you are sending?

Comment: Thanks for your response. @PaulSamsotha  Here is my request:  {
 "product[]": [
  "2",
  "3",
  "4"
 ],
 "title": "客户【上海XX有限公司】的订单",
 "amount": "9999",
 "comment": "测试",
 "accId": "1",
 "ownerId": "14"
}

Comment: @PaulSamsotha  And the content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: 1) That's not form-urlencoded data. That's JSON. 2) product[] is not how the lists works. it is meant to be used for multiple `product`(s). e.g.`product=1&product=2`

Comment: @PaulSamsotha It seems form-data. I just want to use the field value mapping automatically by BeanParam in resteasy. If I use json content-type, I have to analyse the json and set value....

Comment: And here is my js: `code` let param = $.extend(vm.formOrderCreate, {
                  'accId': vm.formOrderCreate.acc.id,  
                  'ownerId': vm.formOrderCreate.owner.id  
                 });
                 
           $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
            url:  baseURL + '/rest/poservice/create',
            data:  param,
            success: function(resp){ ... ... `code`

Comment: And what I am telling you is that you cannot use "product[]". It doesn't work like that for the form data. You can only use `product` multiple times. I don't know now the jQuery serialized the Javascript object, but it has to be in the form `product=1&product=2` not `product[]=[1,2]`

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. I use json content-type instead. And I found json can init the bean field automatically also. @PaulSamsotha